# C# .NET Regex matching too much

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse strings like `<stuff>{<more stuff>}` into two groups `<stuff>` and `<more stuff>`.

My regex is simple:

```
@"^((?>[^\{]*))(\{.*\})?$"
```

Some online regex parsers show it works but it doesn't work in `.net`. Either I end up with the 2nd group having the same match or the 1st group also matching the brackets {}

e.g.,

`test{case}` gives:

`test{case}` and `{case}` or

`test{case}` and `test{case}`.

(Depending on some slight mods to the regex)

What am I doing wrong?

Also: How to extend this to the CSV case(the above would be for one element) with optional last comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is correct, but I suspect you're having trouble with the groups.

Try naming the groups instead (using the syntax `(?<name>...)`) (you also had an atomic capture on the first group which I don't think you'll need here):

```
@"^(?<stuff>[^\{]*)(?<moreStuff>\{.*\})?$"
```

Now you can access the results via:

```
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    var stuff = match.Groups["stuff"];
    var moreStuff = match.Groups["moreStuff"];
}
```

Comment: The atomic make it work better but might not be needed. Why does it matter if I used named groups? Indexing through a string vs an integer shouldn't matter? Ok, It seems that I guess there is a group that is being matched greadily. Care to explain why? e.g., using named groups work but only because the I get 3 groups instead of 2 and my indexing was, hence, wrong. This occurs with your example. Maybe because group 0 is the full match?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by trouble with your groups. Group `0` is the full match, group `1` is the first group, etc.

Comment: Ok, well, it works. Do you happen to know how to extend the example "recursively match" groups if I wanted to string these along separated by commas? e.g., somestuff1{somestuff2}, somestuff3{somestuff4}. something like @"^((?<stuff>[^\{]*)(?<moreStuff>\{.*\})?,\s)?$" (which won't work but shows where I'm trying to go. Basically CSV's but I'd like to be able extract an arbitrary number.